# NSDateFormatter returns nil in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
NSString *localTime;
NSString *lUTCTime = @"12-06-2015 14:34:10";
```

Date i am receiving from server

```
NSString *dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSTimeZone *inputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputDateFormatter setTimeZone:inputTimeZone];
[inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
//    NSString *inputString = lUTCTime;
NSDate *date = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:lUTCTime];//inputString
NSTimeZone *outputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputDateFormatter setTimeZone:outputTimeZone];
[outputDateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
NSString *outputString = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];//@"12-06-2015 09:46:05"


NSDate *fromDate = [outputDateFormatter dateFromString:outputString];
NSDate *otherDate = [NSDate date];
```

Here the conversion is getting fail and returning nil.

```
NSString *temp = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:otherDate];
otherDate = [outputDateFormatter dateFromString:temp];
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Why are you taking a date `otherDate`, turning it into a string, and then turning it back into a date?

Comment: I am receiving the some past XXXXX date from server. Using that date and my current date, i am calculating the how many days back the question is posted. Other date is current date.

Comment: No, you're not. All you are doing is trying to turn a date into a string and right back into a date. Moreover, that is not how you do date math. If you want to know the difference in days between two dates, do not use NSDateFormatter at all - do date math.

Comment: NSString *temp = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:otherDate];
otherDate = [outputDateFormatter dateFromString:temp];                      Sorry, Forget about the last two lines. Those are unnecessary lines.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I repeat, to do date math you should not be using NSDateFormatter at all. The only thing you need NSDateFormatter for is to turn the date string from the server into a date.

Comment: Can you suggest me what to do exactly. I want to convert server time (UTC) to my current device based time.

Comment: You do not need to convert any times. An NSDate is an NSDate.

Comment: In other words, just do the first part of your code _and stop_. You now have the date. Now do date math.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your code works just fine:

```
NSString *lUTCTime = @"12-06-2015 14:34:10";
NSString *dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSTimeZone *inputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputDateFormatter setTimeZone:inputTimeZone];
[inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
NSDate *date = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:lUTCTime];
```

Now *stop*. `date` is now an NSDate. That's what you wanted and it's all you need. Throw the date formatter away; you needed it only in order to turn the date string into date. You have finished with it.

Now work purely with NSDate (and NSDateComponents, NSCalendar, etc.) in order to do any desired date math.

Comment: The result is NSDate, that's fine. ==========For example, My device timezone(Panama city, Nicaragua) is GMT+6. Assume, current date is 15-06-2015 14:34:10. The result should be in Days, hours and minutes between these two dates.

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you. Read the last paragraph of my answer. Do some research. Read the docs on date math. There is even a WWDC video about it.

Comment: we are facing the issue. it's not on iOS 8.3. I'm getting error NSDate is nil...Can you please help ?